# Under what condition on $f$ is $f(d(x,y))$ a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

Under what condition on $f$ is $\rho:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by

$$\rho(x,y)=f(d(x,y))$$ also a metric?

My attempt (intuitively):

$f$ must be defined everywhere (well defined) i.e. it has to be continuous and differentiable. I am also thinking that for the triangle inequality to hold, $f$ must be monotonically increasing.

Does $f(x)=tan^{-1}(x)$ work?

Comment: You need $f(0) = 0$, obviously enough.

Comment: @AlfredYerger, wait is it sufficient to state that $f$ must satisfy the 4 properties of a metric? Positivity, nondegeneracy, homogeneity, and triangle inequality?

Comment: It's clear that you need
\begin{align}
f(0) = 0
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y). 
\end{align}

Comment: I'm assuming $x, y\geq 0$.

Comment: @JackyChong, it's assumed that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ but I don't know if I can assume that $x,y \geq 0$. I know that $f$ must be monotonically increasing for the triangle inequality to hold. If the above are the only requirements, $f$ doesn't have to be continuous or differentiable at all?

Comment: I think you want $f(x) \geq 0$ if $x \geq 0$.

Comment: There is certainly no need for $f$ to be differentiable.  I don't think it needs to be continuous either, but funny things might happen to the topology with that.

Comment: @JackyChong, ok, so this looks very much similar to the properties of $d(x,y)$. In which case $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: We also need $f(0) = 0$, and $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Consider the function
\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x\leq 0\\
1 & \text{ if } x>0
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
Suppose $d$ is a metric, then we see that $f(d(x, y))$ is also a metric since
\begin{align}
f(d(x, x)) = f(0) = 0
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
f(d(x, y)) \leq f(d(x, z)) + f(d(y, z)). 
\end{align}

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, is this incorrect: $f = 0$ iff $x=y$? Under what condition on $f$ will $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$?

Comment: clearly, my example indicates otherwise.

Comment: @ozarka for **any** $f$, we have $\rho(x,y) = \rho(y,x)$

Comment: It's silly to consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$; there's no reason not to restrict to $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, yes. I think by virtue of $d(x,y)$ being a metric, the domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$ and for $\rho$ to be a metric, the codomain must be all non-negative reals.

Comment: @JackyChong, thank you. I think I understand now. If $f(x)=tan^{-1}(x)$, I see that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\geq 0$ of $x\geq 0$.But since $tan^{-1}\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ I am not sure if the triangle inequality holds...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan(x)%2Barctan(y)-arctan(x%2By)+%3C0

Comment: So, it seems like $\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)\geq \arctan(x+y)$ when $x, y\geq 0$.

Comment: Note that $f$ does _not_ have to be monotonic.  For instance, $f(x)$ could randomly take values in $[1,2]$ over all positive values of $x$, and this will always satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @JackyChong, I forgot to realize that $x,y\geq 0$. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ozarka: I would suggest you unaccept Zelos Malum's answer, as it is very far from a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's check the conditions that a metric must satisfy

1. $d(x,y)\ge 0$
2. $d(x,y) \iff x=y$
3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
4. $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge d(x,z)$

Those are the conditions for a metric. So clearly we must have that $f(x)\ge 0$ when $x\ge 0$ to sate the first condition. For the second condition we must have that $f(0)=0$, but it is important also that that there is no non-zero $r$ such that $f(r)=0$ as otherwise we pick $x,y$ such that $d(x,y)=r$ and then the second condition is broken. The third is trivially true. For the last one we need to have 
$$f(d(x,z))=\rho(x,z)\le\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)=f(d(x,y))+f(d(y,z))$$
which means we must have the function being subadditive, that is $f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y).$

Comment: This is necessary (if you want $f$ to work for any possible $d$), but it's far from obvious that it's sufficient.

Comment: Can't say everything, some fun must be left for the reader! :P

Comment: In fact, it is not sufficient.  For instance, $f(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$ is subadditive, but it doesn't work because (for instance) $1,3,3$ satisfies the triangle inequality in all permutations but $1,1/3,1/3$ does not.

Comment: @EricWofsey ,thank you! Can I say that $f$ must be increasing? On second thought, if I impose such restriction $tan^{-1}(x)$ is not increasing when $x\geq 0$ but I know this function has to work...

Comment: @ozarka: No, $f$ does not need to be increasing (see [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983860/under-what-condition-on-f-is-fdx-y-a-metric/1983888?noredirect=1#comment4072832_1983860)).  I don't know why you say $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not increasing though; it is!

Comment: @EricWofsey,oh I missed your previous comment! Thank you for the clarification. From the comment above with counterexample $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, all I'm getting is that $f(x)\geq x$. Could you provide additional hint(s)?

Comment: @ozarka: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean or how you're getting $f(x)\geq x$.  $f(x)=1/x$ fails because you could have a triangle in $X$ with side lengths $1$, $3$, and $3$, but then with respect to $\rho$ you would get a triangle with side lengths $1$, $1/3$, and $1/3$ and $1/3+1/3<1$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I was going off of your counterexample - trying to impose a condition so that $f(x)=1/x$ is not allowed. The reason $1/d(x,y)$ cannot be a metric is because for $d(x,y)>1$, you're getting $f(d(x,y))<1$. Is the additional conditional blatantly obvious?

Comment: @ozarka: No, I don't know a simple way to formulate the additional condition (if I did I would have posted it as an answer!).  You can of course just say "whenever $a,b,c$ satisfy the triangle inequality in all permuations, so do $f(a),f(b),f(c)$", but this is not very concrete...